# TopLayoutGuide and BottomLayoutGuide Deprecated in iOS 11

Tags: autolayout, ios11

`UIViewController`'s `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` are deprecated in iOS 11. What should be the replacement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Previously in your `UIViewController`:

```
customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
customView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Now you should use:

```
customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
customView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Note the change from `bottomAnchor` to `topAnchor`. This is because the top layout guide was a rectangle at the top of the view controller, so in order to constraint your content to the top, you wanted the bottom anchor of the guide. The new safe are layout guide is a rectangle portion of the view unobscured by bars and other content, so you want the top anchor. And vice-versa for the bottom layout guide.

Comment: I can't seem to do this with the visual layout format language. Would you have a example for it? I'm getting '-[NSLayoutYAxisAnchor nsli_superitem]: unrecognized selector'

Comment: What the `view` does mean in `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`? Is it `customView`?