# BottomLayoutGuide iOS 10 vs iOS 11

Tags: ios, view, tableview, banner, safearealayoutguide

Good day!

I have a trouble with placing a bannerView in my app.
Its a static TableViewController, and the bannerView is supposed to be at the bottom of the screen. I did everything as it is said in Google Mobile SDK.

```
func positionBannerViewFullWidthAtBottomOfView(_ bannerView: UIView) {
    view.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                           attribute: .leading,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: view,
                           attribute: .leading,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                           attribute: .trailing,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: view,
                           attribute: .trailing,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                           attribute: .top,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 0)
        ]
    )
```

This is how it loads now, slightly below the view:

[image]

My guess problem is in the last Constraint, bottomLayoutGuide seems to be leading somewhere when it should not. When I remove last constraint it appears right below NavigationBar.

[image]

This problem does not occur on iOS 11+, only on previous versions.

Comment: what is the issue can you elabrate more?

Comment: The issue is that according to constraints from post 1, the banner should be precisely at the bottom of the view, I should not be scrolling down to see it. It loads perfectly on simulator with iOS 11, but not on 10, 9.. etc.

Comment: replace bottom constraint with this :  NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 0)

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651022/how-to-create-layout-constraints-programmatically

Comment: This did not help :(

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534851/toplayoutguide-and-bottomlayoutguide-deprecated-in-ios-11